# Github actions/cache@v2: unrecognized option: posix in the post job

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm using Github Actions to implement a CI pipeline in my project. Currently, I'm trying to use actions/cache@v2 to cache `yarn cache dir` to improve the pipeline time. Unfortunately, always that the actions/cache@v2 runs I'm getting an error in the post-job saying: `/bin/tar: unrecognized option: posix`. The complete log is:

```
Post job cleanup.
/usr/bin/docker exec  4decc52e7744d9ab2e81bb24c99a830acc848912515ef1e86fbb9b8d5049c9cf sh -c "cat /etc/*release | grep ^ID"
/bin/tar --posix -z -cf cache.tgz -P -C /__w/open-tuna-api/open-tuna-api --files-from manifest.txt
/bin/tar: unrecognized option: posix
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.

Usage: tar c|x|t [-ZzJjahmvokO] [-f TARFILE] [-C DIR] [-T FILE] [-X FILE] [--exclude PATTERN]... [FILE]...

Create, extract, or list files from a tar file

    c   Create
    x   Extract
    t   List
    -f FILE Name of TARFILE ('-' for stdin/out)
    -C DIR  Change to DIR before operation
    -v  Verbose
    -O  Extract to stdout
    -m  Don't restore mtime
    -o  Don't restore user:group
    -k  Don't replace existing files
    -Z  (De)compress using compress
    -z  (De)compress using gzip
    -J  (De)compress using xz
    -j  (De)compress using bzip2
    -a  (De)compress using lzma
    -h  Follow symlinks
    -T FILE File with names to include
    -X FILE File with glob patterns to exclude
    --exclude PATTERN   Glob pattern to exclude
Warning: Tar failed with error: The process '/bin/tar' failed with exit code 1
```

I'm following the example of the official [action cache repository](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#node---yarn). Here a snippet of my CI.yml

```
  # Configure cache
  - name: Get yarn cache directory path
    id: yarn-cache-dir-path
    run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"

  - uses: actions/cache@v2
    id: yarn-cache # use this to check for `cache-hit` (`steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'`)
    with:
      path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('yarn.lock') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
```

Because of the above error, the cache is not created and the pipeline time is not improved. I've tried changing the `hasFiles` expression and the entire key, but no success.

My question is: Am I making some mistake in the use of Action Cache? Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a non-standard `PATH` or running this action inside a Docker container or other non-default OS?

Comment: @bk2204 Yes, it's running inside a Docker container. You can access the full workflow file [here](https://gist.github.com/peresbruno/941582c1fc9308ab9a3bbcbf5ecc4fd2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you're running inside an Alpine Linux-based container.  Alpine Linux is designed for small size, and as a result it replaces many of the standard GNU utilities with those from busybox, a multi-call binary.  Your version of `tar` is one of those.

The `actions/cache@v2` action uses `tar --posix`, which tells `tar` to create a standard pax-format archive.  pax archives are a form of tar archive that can handle arbitrarily long filenames, huge file sizes, and other types of metadata that tar archives cannot.  This format is specified by POSIX and is a better choice than GNU tar-style archives because it works across a variety of systems and isn't specified by what one implementation does, in addition to being more featureful.

However, the version of `tar` shipped as part of busybox doesn't support the `--posix` option, and as a result this command fails.  If you want to use the `actions/cache@v2` GitHub Action, then you need to provide a version of GNU or BSD (libarchive) `tar` earlier in your `PATH` before running it so that that command can be used instead of busybox's.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, your suggestion is to change the Alpine Linux to another distro? Or is there another way to achieve the same goal? Thanks!

Comment: You can either use a different distro than Alpine (there are Debian-based Node images) or install a different tar implementation (e.g., bsdtar or GNU tar) and put it earlier in your `PATH`.

Comment: You can run `apk add --no-cache tar` to get a compatible tar.